# Replacing numbers in the same range

Tags: awk, sed

I have a tab delim file1 where the first column looks like

```
1
1
6
6
6
1A
1A
1B
2
2
2
2
3
4
4A
Z
Z
```

I wanna replace so that `1 = 1, 1A = 2, 1B = 3, 2 = 4, 3 = 5, 4 = 6, 4A = 7, 6 = 8, Z = 9`
Output should then be

```
1
1
8
8
8
2
2
3
4
4
4
4
5
6
7
9
9
```

I've sen other posts saying that to avoid cumulative substitution I should work my way from bigger values to smaller ones and do the multiple substitutions using:

```
sed -e 's/a/b/g ; s/b/d/g' file
```

but I have 60 substitutions to make.

Is there a way I can do this in a loop or some other alternative instead of writing 60 substitutions

Notice each element is repeated different times and they can be numbers and characters, but I'm substituting them all for numbers 1-60, and in a predefined order and not in the order they show up. My file has other columns with the same characters, but I only wanna substitute things in the 1st column.

Comment: You're going to have to create a mapping between old and new values regardless of the solution you end up going with, so I would just write the 60 substitutions and be done with it.

Comment: All right! Better get started then. Thxs

Comment: Your description `1 = 1, 1A = 2, 1B = 3, 2 = 4, 3 = 5, 4 = 6, 4A = 7, 6 = 8, Z = 9` doesn't explain how `6` in the input becomes `4` in the output. Please make sure your description matches your example and also make sure your example includes cases that could get messed up if the translation happens in the wrong order.

Comment: Typo fixed. Thxs for noticing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a mapping file with your search and replacement strings as:

```
cat mapping
1   1
1A  2
1B  3
2   4
3   5
4   6
4A  7
6   8
Z   9
```

Then simply use this `awk` to get all substitutions in single command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR == FNR{key[$1]=$2; next} $1 in key{$1=key[$1]} 1' mapping file
```

```
1
1
8
8
8
2
2
3
4
4
4
4
5
6
7
9
9
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following(add additional `FS=OFS="\t"` in `BEGIN` section in case you have TAB separated Input_file and you need output too in TAB form).

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  key="1,1A,1B,2,3,4,4A,6,Z"
  value="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
  split(key,array1,",")
  num=split(value,array2,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    pair[array1[i]]=array2[i]
  }
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i in pair){
      $i=pair[$i]
    }
  }
}
1
'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

for single numerical digit prefix, this will work without manual mapping

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]; next} 
       FNR==1  {asorti(a,b); for(k in b) c[b[k]]=k} 
               {print c[$1]}' file{,}

1
1
8
8
8
2
2
3
4
4
4
4
5
6
7
9
9
```

note that 6 is mapped to 8, not 4 as in your sample output.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/$/\n:1=1:1A=2:1B=3:2=4:3=5:4=6:4A=7:6=8:Z=9/;s/^(\S+)(.*)\n.*:\1=([^:]*).*/\3\2/;P;d' file
```

Append a lookup table to each line and use pattern matching and back references to translate the first column to the required string.

N.B. Lines that have no matching lookup will not be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want to use consecutive numbers starting at 1 as the replacements, all you need is:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    split("1 1A 1B 2 3 4 4A 6 Z",tmp)
    for (i in tmp) {
        map[tmp[i]] = i
    }
    FS = OFS = "\t"
}
$1 in map { $1 = map[$1] }
1' file
1
1
8
8
8
2
2
3
4
4
4
4
5
6
7
9
9
1
```